# How to show Video in place of Video URL

Tags: android, json, video

In my app i am *fetching data into ListView using JSON*, and whenever user do tap on any of the list Item showing that particular in another activity.

JSON contains **4 json objects**, namely:- id, name, description, url

where **url** is the *online mp4 video URLs*

Like i am **passing name, description** in a same way i am **passing video url** in string format, but here i need a small change, how to show that ***video on activity in place of URL ?***

I am new in android but i felt that only necessary code is ok to show you how i am doing instead of full source

so here we go,

```
public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

// json video url object

private static final String TAG_URL = "url";  

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_URL);

        TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

        lblMobile.setText(mobile);
      }
}
```

**activity_single_contact.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp">

  <!-- Mobile Label -->
  <!-- in place of TextView want to show Video -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/mobile_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edited:** for new learners like me

```
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(mobile);
    VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
```

..........................................

```
   <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Comment: Replace textView with ImageView and set video Thumbnil to the imageView. that will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`VideoView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) in android

Do like this in onCreate

```
  String url = "http://example.com/videl.mp4";
     VideoView movie=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
     movie.setVideoURI(url);
     movie.start();
```

Comment: nice solution, but it is starting playing video, and i want to allow user to tap on video to view, like we can see in many apps, how can i do this?

Comment: then write is code inside the Clicklistener of the button

Comment: second solution not too clear and yet not done, anyways you helped in playing video thanks for that